# No icon for addon created with jpm

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I can't seem to get my addon icon to show up when I use `jpm`. The relevant items in `package.json` are

```
"icon": "icon.png",
"icon64": "icon64.png",
```

and when I unpack the extension, I see them in `install.rdf` as

```
<em:iconURL>icon.png</em:iconURL>
<em:icon64URL>icon64.png</em:icon64URL>
```

They are 48x48 and 64x64px `png` files, respectively.

Both of those files are in the root directory of the extension. If I read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#icon) correctly, I shouldn't even have to specify those names, as they are the default.

I don't see any extension icon in the Addons-manager. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [icon64 is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#icon64) and "`not available when using jpm.`"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/mozilla/jpm/issues/197) with jpm, and I just updated that bug report asking for an update on what we can do about it. It's a mystery to me why it doesn't work as-is.

Comment: Is this fixed? Because I am still having problems trying to get this to work. `resource://@your-addon-name/data/your-icon-name.png` fails. My package.json has an GUID because the web-based add-on verifier at AMO says I need to use my existing GUID. I tried @{GUID}, @GUID, GUID, with and without /data/ (as the same logos used for interface button and about page are in /data/). But I can't seem to get any of those logos to appear as well. Tried with and without a name defined in package.json and @name in uri with /data/, icon in /data/ but without /data/ in uri, and in root. jpm git master 1.0.7

Answer (score 3):

it's a bug.

If you're working on jpm 1.0.1, the only way it works is:

```
"icon": "resource://@youraddonname/icon.png",
```

rename your icon as "icon". Don't know why it works that way..

Comment: It has been a few months, and @montjoile's answer is still the way to do it

Comment: Keep in mind that if you define an id on your package.json then you need to insert the id. For example with an id : "{abcd......cdef}" the link is "resource://abcd......cdef/icon.png".

Answer (score 0):

For new `jpm` tool, you can use like this:

`"icon :" "resource://<ADDONID>/data/icon.png"`

**Note:** In cfx you have `id` that is some things like `jid1-O1iNqbs7ifwqvA` but in new `jpm` tool , we dont have any id, instead the `name` field use instead of @jetpack...

for example for an old cfx addon with id of `jid1-O1iNqbs7ifwqvA` we must do like this

```
"id": "jid1-O1iNqbs7ifwqvA@jetpack",
"icon": "resource://jid1-O1iNqbs7ifwqvA-at-jetpack/data/icon.png"
```

also you can add icons for `menu bar`, `addon page`, `open menu Menu` like below:

```
"icons":{
"16":"./data/icon-16.png",
"32":"./data/icon-32.png",
"64":"./data/icon-64.png",
"128":"./data/icon-128.png",
"256":"./data/icon-256.png",
"512":"./data/icon-512.png"
},
```

useful Links:

- [Learn Make Package.json
  file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json)
- [JPM Manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm)